# Prevent Error Message from Appearing When Hitting Cancel of Opening a File

Tags: c#, winforms

This seems so simple, but I have been trying to get this to work properly, but I just can't. Here is the original code:

```
ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     mFileName = ofd.FileName;
}
```

Problem is, if the user hits the cancel button on the dialog box, then a bunch of my other code continues to execute, such as opening the database connection and such, which is unnecessary since the user selected cancel. So I then tried:

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    return;
}
else if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    mFileName = ofd.FileName;
}
```

While this prevents the problem before, another arises. If the user selects cancel, it stops. But then it will open a second dialog box, which it shouldn't.

I can't seem to only open one dialog box, if the user hits cancel return, else if the user hits open, then it continues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are calling `ShowDialog()` multiple times. It returns a [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum so you can store it in a variable the like this:

```
DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
```

Then you can work on it multiple times without having to show the dialog again:

```
if(result == DialogResult.OK) {
    // OK!
}
else if(result == DialogResult.Cancel) {
    return; // Exit function
}
else {
    // Anything else you need to do
}
```

Comment: Yes. Makes much more sense. Thank you.